# Help with relations in views

Tags: 7, entities, views

Have been struggled with this problems for days and I wonder if someone could have a look at it? I have tried me sleepless to achieve a certain table in views between three content types which has relations between them, using entity reference. The biggest issue is that I can't wrap my head around how I should set up my relations.

Since this is driving me crazy, have I made this pdf that describes what I have now and what I'm trying to achieve.

http://themesh.se/problemDesc/problemdescription.pdf

Hope some of you have some spare time and if the simple answer is "This won't work" will that also be satisfying at the moment.

Comment: Place the complete question please for the archive of the site. Linked content might be removed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the rows that you annotated with "Duplicates", you could use the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module. From its project page:

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.

Assuming that would indeed remove the duplicate rows, the "*What I get*" should match with "*What I try to achieve*". So with that the setup of your relationships like you already defined them should be OK also (I can't think of any other missing piece to complete your puzzle).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice Pierre, I downloaded and enabled the module as you suggested and got it almost to work! :D

It removed the duplicates but seems to be confusing what type C on the second row is pointing at. I have confirmed that the is set up correctly as in my previous pdf.

Once again, here is a link that shows the progress. Just one row that is not working as it should.

http://themesh.se/problemDesc/problemdescription-2.pdf

Comment: After closer inspection, it seems to have removed the fifth row as well.